# SQL - An explanation of != 'NULL'

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

My SSMS code is as follows:

```
Select top(50)
From FilteredContact
Where statuscode = 1 
and emailaddress1 != 'NULL' 
and telephone1 != 'NULL' 
and address1_line1 != 'NULL'
```

I realize that ideally, the last three lines are to be formatted as follows:

```
and emailaddress1 IS NOT NULL
and telephone1 IS NOT NULL
and address1_line1 IS NOT NULL
```

However, my original code actually worked completely fine. Why is that? I thought NULL was an unknown value, not a string value equal to 'NULL'

If anyone knows, an explanation would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: `'NULL'` is a string, it is not `NULL`. Sometimes people store "bad data" in the database.

Comment: Looks like the string `'NULL'` is being stored in the tables rather than the value `NULL`

Comment: @LONG Thanks for the quick reply! I tested the code with ansi_nulls on and off, and nothing changed.

Comment: I don't believe this has anything to do with ANSI_NULLS setting. That would make the difference between the functionality of `column <> NULL` vs `column IS NOT NULL`. That's not your question though. I believe @user2864740 is correct and you have 'NULL' string literal in your data (or did).

Comment: Yes, as people mentioning here, that's not `NULL` it's a string literal `'NULL'`. The literal word/text 'NULL' as opposed to the absence of data represented by the word *NULL*.

Comment: @AllieWolfers, check @ user2864740's comment, hes right :)

Comment: I'm fairly new to SQL, but I'm pretty sure the table values aren't just string values equal to 'NULL.' The values are highlighted yellow and say NULL, if it was just a string value, wouldn't it have just a white background? https://postimg.cc/image/7fag2qoo7/

Comment: so when you say... it worked completely fine... did you get the right results?  or did the query just eliminate string data saying 'NULL' and you still obtained records  with null values or the null values went away as well because anything compared to null is null thus not true thus eliminated from records returned...

Comment: It returned the first 50 records where statuscode = 1 and emailaddress1, telephone1, and address1_line1 were not NULL. I got perfectly valid results (for my purposes).

Comment: so NULL !='NULL' evaluates to NULL (not true) thus record not returned.  Not ideal imo; your check for is not null makes more sense.

Comment: Yeah, IS NOT NULL is definitely the correct way to go here - I just wasn't sure why me comparing cells to 'NULL' still removed all records with NULL values. Like everyone else is saying, I guess it's just bad data and my cells had string values rather than true null values. Thanks to everyone for all the help, it's very much appreciated!

Comment: @AllieWolfers It doesn't sound like bad data... any comparison with `<>` will remove `NULL` because `NULL` is an unknown and can't be compared with `= != <>`.  You have to do `<> 'value' or IS NULL` to avoid losing records with `NULL` cells.  Change your filter to `!= 'hoobla doobla'` and you'll see the `NULL` still get removed.

Comment: AaronDietz Yes! I just found that out from reading @krokodilko 's answer. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, my original code actually worked completely fine.

Worked by accident. If for example `emailaddress1 ='NULL'` (a string value consisting of four characters: N U L L), then the condition evaluates to FALSE, and is incorrect. Since the email address is unlikely to be `NULL`, then yes - it worked perfectly :)

---

See this answer for a long explanation: [NOT IN selection with NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46324437/not-in-selection-with-null-values/46328830#46328830)

In short:

> **Comparisons with NULL and the three-valued logic (3VL)**
>
> Since Null is not a member of any data domain, it is not considered a
>   "value", but rather a marker (or placeholder) indicating the absence
>   of value. Because of this, comparisons with Null can never result in
>   either True or False, but always in a third logical result,
>   Unknown.[8] The logical result of the expression below, which compares
>   the value 10 to Null, is Unknown:
>
> SELECT 10 = NULL       -- Results in Unknown
>
> so that both comparisons:
>   **x = NULL and x <> NULL evaluates to NULL(unknown).**

In your condition, say `and telephone1 != 'NULL'`, if `telephone` is NULL, then the whole conditions evaluates to NULL, which is treated as `false` condition in the WHERE clause.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you very much! It indeed was a coincidence, replacing the 'NULL' with any string value yields the same result. NULL values cannot be compared to string values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Or as others have suggested `NULL` is being stored as string.

Answer (score 0):

`emailaddress1 != 'NULL'` compares `emailaddress1` and the string `'NULL'`. Since the field is almost certainly a string, the type matches well enough. And since no one's going to have an email address of `'NULL'`, the comparison won't eliminate valid rows (which have non-null, but also non-`'NULL'`, values).

Where things get a bit less intuitive is when the field's value is actually `NULL`. In standard SQL, the result of just about any comparison with a null value is `UNKNOWN` (which is generally treated the same as `NULL`). Since the DBMS only returns rows where the condition is true, it won't return that row.

So the comparison works unless the string `'NULL'` would otherwise be valid in that field.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't involve `ANSI_NULL` (I don't think). You are trying to match a string in your where clause. When you look for `!='NULL'`, you are asking SSMS to return anything that is not the string "NULL". Since `NULL` is an unknown and all comparisons to it will be `NULL`, it will only return other valid strings.

```
DECLARE @testing TABLE (ID INT, items VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @testing (ID, items)
VALUES 
(1,'blah'),
(2,'blahhhhhh'),
(3,'NULL'),
(4,NULL)


SELECT * 
FROM @testing 

--will return values that are NOT the string 'NULL' and values that are not NULL
--because NULL compared to anything is NULL
SELECT * 
FROM @testing 
WHERE items != 'NULL'

SELECT * 
FROM @testing 
WHERE items <> 'NULL'

--will return all string values that have a non-NULL value
SELECT * 
FROM @testing 
WHERE items IS NOT NULL
```